# Summation of Roots of Cubic Equation

Tags: summation, summation-method, roots-of-cubics

I was attempting the recent May/June 2023, CAIE past paper for Further Mathematics variant 12. The question states:

> **2**      The cubic equation $x^3+4x^2+6x+1=0$ has roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$. 
>  
>              (a) Find the value of $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2$. 
>              (b) Use standard results from the list of formulae (MF19) to show that $$\sum^n_{r=1} \big((\alpha + r)^2+(\beta+r)^2+(\gamma+r)^2\big)=n(n^2+an+b),$$             where $a$ and $b$ are constants to be determined.

For the (a) part, my working is correct as follows:

$$\big( \sum \alpha \big)^2 = \sum \alpha^2 +2\sum\alpha \beta$$
$$16=\alpha^2-2(6)$$
$$\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=4$$

For the (b) part, my working is incorrect according to marking scheme. Realizing that $(\alpha+r)^2=\alpha^2+2\alpha+r^2$ and using above information, my working is:
$$\sum^n_{r=1} \big((\alpha + r)^2+(\beta+r)^2+(\gamma+r)^2\big)=\sum^n_{r=1} 3r^2-16r+4$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)(2n+1)-8n(n+1)+4n$$
$$=n\bigg(\big(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\big)(2n+1)-8n-4\bigg)$$
$$=n\bigg(n^2+\frac{n}{2}+n+\frac{1}{2}-8n-4\bigg)$$
$$=n\bigg(n^2 - \frac{15}{2}n-\frac{7}{2}\bigg)$$

Is my attempt correct for the part (b)? The [marking scheme](https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Mathematics%20-%20Further%20(9231)/2023/9231_s23_ms_12.pdf) has the solution in section 2(b). Am I making a mistake or the marking scheme is wrong? I am losing where how they found the sum of $2r(-4)$, where (MF19) states $\sum^n_{r=1}r=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$. It is unclear even with guidance how they got it.

Comment: The summand should be $3r^2-8r+4$ instead of $3r^2-16r+4$

Comment: @AlanAbraham I see, thanks. I still question the marking scheme, where did the $\lambda$ come from? Should it be $\gamma$ or am I wrong again?

Comment: They probably just typoed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you want to know follows from
$$
(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)=x^3-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)x^2+(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)x-\alpha\beta\gamma,
$$

$$
(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+2(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma),
$$
and
$$
(\alpha+r)^2+(\beta+r)^2+(\gamma+r)^2=\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2+2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)r+3r^2.
$$
Well, you'll also need
$$
\sum_{r=1}^nr=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{r=1}^nr^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of using other two summations, I particularly made calculation mistake in $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$.